# Forever channel terminating the program and go channel with RabbitMQ consumer

Tags: go, rabbitmq, deadlock, channel, producer-consumer

I am writing program in Go and also RMQ consumer with go channel and came to these scenarios.

**"go forever channel" blocks the main thread until it gets stop signal from other go routine.**

But below program 1 tells deadlock error, and **program 2** works fine without deadlock error,
why it's happening?

**Program 1** : Go routine printing element in loop and deadlock error

```
package main
import "fmt"

func main() {
    stopProgram := make(chan bool)

    go func() {
      for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
         fmt.Println("hello ",i)
      }
      // Send signal through stopProgram to stop loop
      //stopProgram <- true
    }()


   // your problem will wait here until it get stop signal through channel
   <-stopProgram
   fmt.Println("after forever channel")
}
```

**Output**

```
hello  0                                                                                                                                                      
hello  1                                                                                                                                                      
hello  2                                                                                                                                                      
hello  3                                                                                                                                                      
hello  4                                                                                                                                                      
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!                                                                                                            

goroutine 1 [chan receive]:                                                                                                                                   
main.main()                                                                                                                                                   
        /home/main.go:26 +0x73
```

**Program 2** : Go routing receiving RMQ deliveries in loop and no deadlock

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    )
func main() {
    // assuming some code of registring exchange and queues with rabbitmq

   msgs, err := ch.Consume(
                q.Name, // queue
                "",     // consumer
                true,   // auto-ack
                false,  // exclusive
                false,  // no-local
                false,  // no-wait
                nil,    // args
    )

    stopProgram := make(chan bool)

    go func() {
            for d := range msgs {
                  fmt.Println("reveived message ",d.Body)

            }
    }()

    // your problem will wait here until it get stop signal through channel
    <-stopProgram
    fmt.Println("after forever channel")
}
```

Can anybody clear the things here(i am new to GO) that how forever channel works here ?

**My assumption** - In program 1, go routing ends after printing hello 5 times and there is no infinite execution in current routine/any other routine or stop signal to forever go channel.

If we want to use forever go channel(or block the main Go routine to stay in a specific go routine), we have to make sure these things

1. Either go routines ensures the infinite execution OR
2. Go routine sends the stop signal to forever channel.

Answer (score -1):

You get a `fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!` when your code is waiting on a channel on which no one will be sending anything. So there is no point in waiting for something on that channel.

This can also happen when you try to send something on a channel to which no one is listening.

If you wish to block until a specific go routine completes, the following code using waitgroups is a good best way to do it.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
            fmt.Println("hello ", i)
        }
    }()

    wg.Wait()
}
```

In Program 1, at `<-stopProgram` all other routines are executed. After that, the runtime knows that there is no one sending anything on `stopProgram`. Hence the error

I am not sure if `Program 2` is complete in the sample code you shared. Because even there you are actually not sending anything on `stopProgram`. So <-stopProgram should result in deadlock.